# все время вызывается onLoadFinished

Tags: java, android

Использую `ViewPager` (`FragmentStatePagerAdapter`) с  фрагментами. Для загрузки данных у фрагмента использую `AsyncTaskLoader`, загрузка которого стартует в `onCreate()`. При свайпе между фрагментами все время вызывается `onLoadFinished()`. Я не понимаю, почему так происходит. Насколько я понял, при использовании `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` фрагмент не пересоздается, а лишь отсоединяется. Следовательно, ни `onCreate()`, ни `onLoadFinished()` не должны вызываться, но они вызываются. Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FragmentStatePagerAdapter` убивает фрагменты, когда они становятся вне видимости и сохраняет их State. Когда вы снова возвращаетесь к фрагменту, то срабатывает полный цикл создания, но `savedInstanceState` из предыдущего состояния.
Из документации:

> This version of the pager is more useful when there are a large number of pages, working more like a list view. When pages are not visible to the user, their entire fragment may be destroyed, only keeping the saved state of that fragment.

Отсоединяется фрагмент в `FragmentPagerAdapter` :)

Из полезных ссылок - документация. и вот эта [статья](http://www.truiton.com/2013/06/android-fragmentpageradapter-vs-fragmentstatepageradapter/)